# How do i achieve a title in the middle of a border with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a grid layout:

```
#price {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(3, 1fr) auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3vw;
}
```

And cant seem to find a way to make a responsive title like element like the one containing "lorem" below.

[image: Image of layout]

Comment: Let us see what you've managed so far, HTML and CSS, so we can guide you towards a solution.

Comment: check HTML `fieldset` and `legend`.

Comment: Well i haven't managed anything other than trying position relative, and then just guessing with the minus on top, but that doesn't make it responsive

Comment: @Lal will you post your answer as a solution, so i can flag it as the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving such a functionality, I would suggest you to check the HTML **`fieldset`** and **`legend`**.
As specified in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

> The `<fieldset>` element provides a grouping for a part of an HTML form,
>   with a nested `<legend>` element providing a caption for the `<fieldset>`.

You can then style the `fieldset` and `legend` using `CSS` to obtain the expected result.

Comment: Thanks! And to those wondering margin: auto, will center

Answer (score 1):

html center is hacky but wasnt what i was showing....

showing that

**fieldset** and **legend**  is probably the best use here.

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>monster</legend>
    <center>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </center>
  </fieldset>
```

```
fieldset{
    border: 1px solid #74D5EB;
    font-weight: bold;
}

legend {
    border: 1px solid #74D5EB;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```